# Spark Scala - Split Map, Getkey and so on

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, key-value

I have a text file which contains the following:

```
A>B,C,D
B>A,C,D,E
C>A,B,D,E
D>A,B,C,E
E>B,C,D
```

I would like to write a Spark-Scala script to obtain the following:
(For each left member, we give all right members.)

```
(A,B)
(A,C)
(A,D)
(B,A)
(B,C)
(B,D)
(B,E)
...
```

I tried to go through the map and get the keys to feed a new map with my results but it did not work.

Here is my code (more like pseudo code):

```
import scala.io.Source

// Loading file
val file = sc.textFile("friends.txt")

// MAP
// A;B
// A;C
// ...

var associations_persons_friends:Map[Char,Char] = Map()

var lines = file.map(line=>line.split(">"))

for (line <- lines)
{
    val person = line.key
    
    for (friend <- line.value.split(","))
    {
        associations_persons_friends += (person -> friend)
    }
}

associations_persons_friends.collect()

val rdd = sc.parallelize(associations_persons_friends)
rdd.foreach(println)


// GROUP
// For each possible pair, all associated values
// AB;B-C-D-A-C-D-E


// REDUCE
// For each pair we keep occurrences >= 2
// AB;C-D
```

I wonder if it is possible to write basic code like this in Spark-Scala because I can't find any answer to my needs on the web.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve your requirement with the combination of `map` and `flatMap` as

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("path to the text file")

rdd.map(line => line.split(">")).flatMap(array => array(1).split(",").map(arr => (array(0), arr))).foreach(println)
```

You should have output as

```
(A,B)
(A,C)
(A,D)
(B,A)
(B,C)
(B,D)
(B,E)
(C,A)
(C,B)
(C,D)
(C,E)
(D,A)
(D,B)
(D,C)
(D,E)
(E,B)
(E,C)
(E,D)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks it works. I have difficulties to find how to transform my pseudo code into things like this. Do you have some advices or online resources I could refer to ?

Comment: For the next step for example, I need to do that : For each left member : create a couple for each other left members - For each couple created : take all corresponding right members. I just don't know what kind of documentation I could use to do this from my own.